# Can't connect Google LookerStudio to Amazon Aurora serverless PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-rds-aurora

There are no issues connecting to it from any other environment (local works fine, as does from the Cloud), and the security group is currently totally open. An *actual* PostgreSQL instance, hosted in AWS, had no issue. It's just an Aurora thing. I've created several instances with different configurations. SSL authentication is turned off, and SSL itself is configured to be optional.

"Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request."

[image: broken Aurora support]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that LookerStudio/Google's PostgreSQL connector is incompatible. I was able to connect using a third-party connector; SyncWith's (further down in the list), I think.

[image: SyncWith]

EDIT: It actually looks like, at the time that I tried to connect it, there might've been no tables or databases, or some other infrastructure issue, whereas the third-party connector didn't have that problem. It seems to be connecting with the native connector now just fine.

Comment: Thanks Dustin for mentioning our connector. Its a bit hard to link to a connector in Looker Studio, here's a link to our page that will link you to try the connector (whether or not you're logged in already)

https://syncwith.com/ls/connectors/google-data-studio-postgres